# How do I use jquery's CSS attribute?

Tags: jquery

I'm just trying to reset my css, this doesn't seem to work although it follows the same structure detailed here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp

```
function labelReset(){
    $(".year").css("color" : "#000", "opacity" : "0.5", "size" : "14px");
    $(".dot").css("background-color" : "#000", "width" : "7px", "height" : "7px");
};
```

any thoughts?

Comment: W3Schools is generally crap. If you want to know about the jQuery syntax, go directly to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use brackets `{}`:

```
   function labelReset(){
        $(".year").css({"color" : "#000", "opacity" : "0.5", "size" : "14px"});
        $(".dot").css({"background-color" : "#000", "width" : "7px", "height" : "7px"});
    };
```

For single property: `.css( propertyName, value )`, for multiple properties: `.css( map )`, check [jQuery API css](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: ah I was confused slightly by their one bracket example, thanks very much guys